# Executing stored procedure using linq in c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I made a stored procedure in sql server 2008 which gives me the changes made to a table. I am using Linq to SQL to use this table in C#.
my stored procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getlog 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@p1 int = 0, 
@p2 int = 0
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10)
SET @from_lsn =
 sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_User_Info')
 SET @to_lsn   = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
 SELECT ID_number, Name, Age FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_User_Info
 (@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all');
END
GO
```

The above procedure runs fine in sql server. However when i run this statement using linq in C#

```
        mytestDataContext obj = new mytestDataContext();
        var test=obj.ExecuteCommand("dbo.getlog");
        foreach( var abc in test)
        {}
```

I get this error

> Error 1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int'
>   because 'int' does not contain          a public definition for
>   'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) method returns `Int32` and you can't use magical `foreach` loop using a simple integer.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Int32
The number of rows modified by the executed command.
```

I'm not too much familiar with `DataContext` class but you can use [`DataContext.ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) which returns `IEnumerable<TResult>` and you can use `foreach` loop with it.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>
```

> A collection of objects returned by the query.

Answer (score 7):

`ExecuteCommand` returns an `int`.. not your results.

See MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx

```
public int ExecuteCommand(
    string command,
    params Object[] parameters
)
```

I think you're after `ExecuteQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

I  don't know why do you use foreach-statement, but method 'ExecuteCommand' returns int value, and foreach cycle need object that implements IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

I may be assuming too much, but if you are doing the C# with a recent version of Visual Studio, rather directly specifying the T-SQL call to run the stored procedure as string of literal text, you can drag and drop the stored procedure onto the LINQ to SQL modelling window.  This will add it to the LINQ to SQL data context.

```cs
int param1 = 1;
int param2 = 2;

mytestDataContext obj = new mytestDataContext();
var test=obj.getlog(param1, param2);
foreach( var abc in test)
{
    /* code inside loop */
}
```

The same technique can be used for calling user-defined functions.

Doing this will reduce typing and provide intellisense to help with calling the stored procedures and SQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:
https://github.com/mrmmins/C-StoreProcedureModelBinding

Returns the values as a List, you only need create a simple class with the names and values types, like:

```
var productos = DataReaderT.ReadStoredProceadures<MyCustomModel>(myDbEntityInstance, "dbo.MySPName", _generic);
```

and MyCumtomModel class is something like:

```
public int id {get; set;}
public int salary {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
public string school {get; set;}
```

and generic like:

```
List<Generic> _generic = = new List<Generic>
                          {
                              new Generic
                                  {
                                      Key = "@phase", Type = SqlDbType.Int, Value = "207"
                                  }
                          }
                      };
```

And now, your `products` has the options like: `products.First()`, `products.Count()`, `foreach` etc.